# Selenium WebDriver with IE11: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

Everything worked fine when it was IE9. I upgraded to IE11 and it all started.

My code is failing (`TargetInvocationException`) on initialization of the driver

```
Type[] types = { typeof(InternetExplorerDriver), typeof(ChromeDriver) };
foreach (Type t in types) {
   driver = (IWebDriver)Activator.CreateInstance(t); //Throws exception in title
...
```

It's on WIN7. [I have the registry update as described](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration).

Most places I found something similar have past this step and are getting an exception on using the webdriver. I'm not there yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, on the way another update was missed. While upgrading from IE9 to IE11 this line (from link in OP) is important:

> Additionally, "Enhanced Protected Mode" must be disabled for IE 10 and higher.
>   This option is found in the Advanced tab of the Internet Options dialog.

Do not skip!